# How do I prove αβ = 0 ⇐⇒ α = 0 or β = 0?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let α and β be cardinal numbers. 
Prove that αβ = 0 ⇐⇒ α = 0 or β = 0.

Below is what I have done. Could you please review and point out illogical parts, and things I have missed out? I want to be precise as much as possible. Highlighted and italicized parts are ones that I'm very uncertain for the reason.

Let |X|=α and |Y|=β, where X and Y are sets.

"=>"
Suppose αβ=0, then we show that α=0 or β=0
Since αβ=0, αβ=|X×Y|=0
***Thus, X×Y = {(x,y)|(x∈X)^*(y∈Y)} = ∅***
Therefore, X=∅ or Y=∅.
Hence |X|=0 or |Y|=0. i.e. α=0 or β=0

"<="
Suppose α=0 or β=0, then we show that αβ=0
Since α=0 or β=0, X=∅ or Y=∅.
***Then X×Y = {(x,y)|(x∈X)^*(y∈Y)} = ∅***
Therefore, |X×Y|=0.
Hence αβ = 0.

Comment: If those steps are less than clear to you, then perhaps try looking at it from a contrapositive point of view.  Suppose $\alpha\neq 0$ and $\beta\neq 0$.  Then $X\neq \emptyset$ and $Y\neq \emptyset$, so there is at least one $x\in X$ and at least one $y\in Y$, therefore $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ and $|X\times Y|\geq 1\neq 0$.

Comment: As for $X=\emptyset$ or $Y=\emptyset$ implying $X\times Y=\emptyset$, it suffices to look at each case individually.  Suppose wlog that $X=\emptyset$.  Then $X\times Y$ contains all elements of the form $(x,y)$ where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, but there *aren't any* $x\in X$, so there aren't any $(x,y)$ and $X\times Y$ is empty.

Comment: It's OK... Why the asterisk at the end of the bold-face lines? BTW you can use \land  and \lor for logical "and" , "or" ..... $\land  \lor$.

Comment: This actually turned out to be wrong, since I have used the theorem X×Y = {(x,y)|(x∈X)^(y∈Y)} = ∅ <=> X=∅ or Y=∅. This theorem is just a different form of the problem, thus we can’t use this theorem to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

*Proof.* Suppose for a contradiction that $\alpha \neq 0 \wedge \beta \neq 0$. Let $A$ denote a set of cardinality $\alpha$ and $B$ denote a set of cardinality $\beta$. Since $A$ is non-empty, it has at least one point, call it $a$. Since $B$ is non-empty, it has at least one point, call it $b$. So $A \times B$ has at least one point, namely $(a,b)$. Hence $A \times B$ is non-empty. So $|A \times B| \neq 0$. Ergo $|A||B| \neq 0$. So $\alpha \beta \neq 0$.

Tbh, I'm not quite sure how to verify the one of the principles I used, namely: $$|A| \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists a \in A(\mathrm{True})$$

Idea, anyone? I remark that this doesn't hold intuitionistically.